# TopologyException issue when doing intersection in Geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

When I do overlay processes like intersection, I mostly get:

> :TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING
>   (229971 4.39944e+06, 229971 4.39944e+06) and LINESTRING (229971
>   4.39944e+06, 229971 4.39944e+06) at 229971.08857010119 4399438.0928708706

while during the same process in Arcgis it gets done. After trying many workarounds like setting buffer to no result most of the time(I don't even remember if it ever worked) I think that it has to do with high sensitivity that Geopandas may have to such mistakes in the topology whilst Arc just let slip.

In one intersection for example although it produced such an exception, it eventually produced a result that after checking it seemed fine.Other times it gives the exception and no result. Plus, intersection takes a long time in Geopandas. What should I do with the exception and possibly time?

Also sometimes in intersection it says:`TopologicalError: This operation could not be performed. Reason: unknown`

I hope you can help with this because it is very confusing.Thanks